# dotnet restore fails with "##[error]No files matched the search pattern."

Tags: azure-devops

I am making sure that the path to the project is correct:
path_to_my_project/*.csproj

The only time the restore task completes for me is when I give **/*.csproj (however, the build will fail in this case and I am not sure if this happens because I do the restore for all the projects)

However, this would run the dotnet restore for all the project files in the main repo.
Tried with different projects in the same repo but I still get the same error.

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: Please provide more details: yaml file and error message with fail when you use `**/*.csproj`

Comment: I am using the classic task. Here is the YAML equivalent
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: 'path_to_my_project/*.csproj'

Below is the error I get



##[debug]0 final results
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]No files matched the search pattern.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]No files matched the search pattern.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]No files matched the search pattern.

Finishing: dotnet restore

Answer (score 0):

What you think is the path, may in fact, not be the path. Don't include it. Try **/ProjectName.csproj ... Also, be prepared for a failure if that project relies on the build of another project in the solution. In such a case, you need to build all the projects.